# Prove the form $P_1P_2\cdots P_n + 1$ where $P_k$ is kth prime is not necessary a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-algorithm

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n P_k +1$ where $P_k$ is kth prime. How can I prove exist composite number in this sequence without by examples like $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13 +1=59\times 509$?

Comment: A counterexample would be the way to prove this. Without counterexamples, you need way more complicated theorems about the distributions of the primes. Why is a counterexample not OK for your problem?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Hi I'm just curious. Counterexample doesn't provide much insight, I want a proof which can uncover some secret of the statement.

Comment: @mononoke - This is an unsolved problem of nnumber theory so the probability of getting an answer to this question is extremely low. The best that we can do is show that the $p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n + 1$ misses infinitely many primes.